# How to set logback.xml properties in application.yaml

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, yaml, logback

I have `logback.xml` like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds">

            <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
            <jmxConfigurator/>

            <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
            <logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="DEBUG"/>
            <logger name="com.mypackage" level="WARN"/>

            <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>
                        %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                    </pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>

            <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DynamicThresholdFilter">
                <Key>dynamicLogLevel</Key>
                <DefaultThreshold>DEBUG</DefaultThreshold>
                <MDCValueLevelPair>
                    <value>dynamicLogLevelDEBUG</value>
                    <level>DEBUG</level>
                </MDCValueLevelPair>
                <!-- dynamicLogLevelERROR for testing -->
                <MDCValueLevelPair>
                    <value>dynamicLogLevelERROR</value>
                    <level>ERROR</level>
                </MDCValueLevelPair>
            </turboFilter>

 .....
</configuration>
```

I want to set the logger level, appenders , rolling policy present in `logback.xml` in `application.yaml` .

I have gone through this [Doc](https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure-logback/) but did not find sufficient info.

I'm using `spring-boot 1.4.4-RELEASE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:
My `application.yaml` in some folder(say `C:/configuration/application.yaml`, `c:/configuration/logback.xml`).

In `logback.xml` , we can access `application.yaml` contents using :

```
<property file="${HOME}/configuration/application.yaml"/>
```

for ex: in `application.yaml`

```
LOG_FILE : C:/logs
```

in logback.xml access it:

```
<appender name="MY_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>

...

</appender>
```

But take care of value scanPeriod in

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 10):

The `springProperty` tag is probably all you need. Spring Boot will automatically filter the `source` properties in your configuration file and replace placeholders with the corresponding values from your properties.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds">
    <springProperty name="yourVar" source="key.of.your.yaml.property"/>

    ...${yourVar}...
```

You can see [the details in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/055ace37f006120b0006956b03c7f358d5f3729f).

Comment: ck@Daniel: my logback.xml and application.yaml are in same folder which is not in classpath...looks like logback.xml is not picking the values from application.yaml using <springProperty> ?

Comment: In order to use the above solution, make sure that you have renamed the file to logback-spring.xml

Comment: Shame that the springProperty tag is needed even if the variable names are identical

Answer (score 1):

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    com.pack.test: INFO
  pattern:
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  file: <logPath>/test.log
```

Comment: Please, add some description to your answer.

Comment: More details here: https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure-logback/

Answer (score 0):

in my case

```
    <property resource="application.yaml"/>
```