# Logback to Elasticsearch through yaml or properties

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, logging, microservices, logback

I have many spring based microservice project where I used Logback to Elasticsearch for saving all logs to Elastic search index. I have configured using xml based on some tutorials I got. The configuration is based on xml like as shown below. Instead of xml how can we configure Logback to Elasticsearch using yaml or key value property files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="microserviceName"
        source="spring.application.name" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="profile"
        source="spring.profiles.active" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="myESHost"
        source="logging.esHost" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="myESPort"
        source="logging.esPort" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="myESLoggingLevel"
        source="logging.esLoggingLevel" />  
    <springProperty scope="context" name="consoleLoggingLevel"
        source="logging.consoleLoggingLevel" /> 

    <appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
        <url>http://${myESHost}:${myESPort}/_bulk</url>
        <index>logs-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
        <type>tester</type>
        <loggerName>es-logger</loggerName> <!-- optional -->
        <errorLoggerName>es-error-logger</errorLoggerName> <!-- optional -->
        <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize> <!-- optional (default 104857600) -->
        <maxRetries>3</maxRetries> <!-- optional (default 3) -->
        <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <sleepTime>250</sleepTime> <!-- optional (in ms, default 250) -->
        <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeMdc>false</includeMdc> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize> <!-- optional (default -1 -->
        <authentication class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" /> <!-- optional -->
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>host</name>
                <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
                <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>severity</name>
                <value>%level</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>thread</name>
                <value>%thread</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>stacktrace</name>
                <value>%ex</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>logger</name>
                <value>%logger</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <name>Content-Type</name>
                <value>text/plain</value>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILELOGGER" />
        <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
    </root>

    <logger name="es-error-logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILELOGGER" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="es-logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender name="ES_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <!-- ... -->
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg</pattern> <!-- This pattern is important, otherwise it won't be the raw Elasticsearch format anyomre -->
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648195/how-to-set-logback-xml-properties-in-application-yaml ?

Comment: @Val Thanks for the reply, that SO link actually tells how to import yaml to logback.xml...what I was looking is to convert th logback.xml to yaml file

Comment: Doh, sorry, I got it reversed :-)

Answer (score 2):

That is possible. The configuration would go to the application.yml file (see https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure-logback). Having many services to configure this may not be a solution for you as the configuration gets mangled with each services configuration.

To keep things separated you could use groovy (https://springframework.guru/logback-configuration-using-groovy), if you have it, or try to incorporate a logback.yml via `external configuration files` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) which I have not used yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....I still could not figure it out how to write those `springProperty`, `appender` and `root` in yaml file

Comment: There are xml to yaml converters out there, did you try them? Maybe https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-yaml.